# Error when trying to build docker image from aws lambda node image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

**My Dockerfile**

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14

# Assumes your function is named "app.js", and there is a package.json file in the app directory 
COPY app.js package.json  ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install NPM dependencies for function
RUN npm install

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

**My Code**

```
//import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const Knex = require('knex');
//AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });

const host = //hidden
const user = //hidden
const password=//hidden
const database=//hidden

const connection = {
  ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
  host,
  user,
  password,
  database,
};

// createaconnection
const knex = Knex({
  client:'mysql',
  connection,
});

exports.handler = async () => {
  try {
    const res=await knex('Persons').select();
    console.log(res);
    
    const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(res),
        };
        return response;
   }catch(err){
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

**My project structure**

```
app
├── Dockerfile
├── app.js
└── package.json
```

When I build my image, I'm getting the following error

`When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /`

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Here: COPY app.js package.json  ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}, what is the value of LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT? It should be a path like /var/myapp/, ending with /

Comment: @btafarelo It is taken from the tutorial here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-create-from-base

Comment: ok, the tutorial says: LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT=/var/task, so you are missing the / at the end. I suggest you to set it hardcode as COPY app.js package.json /var/task/ and if it works, you can set another var concatenating var + "/"

Comment: Does my previous comment worked to you?